# Renaming Toolbar based on the bottom navigator

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How do I change Toolbar Titles in different bottom navigation activities, I currently have one displayed in all which is one my manifest

```
android:label="@string/home"
```

but since I have four activities on my bottom navigator how can I rename them all on the activities, I tried adding a toolbar it added below the original, home. Tried renaming manifest particular activities doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

I tried setting titles on the activities like this:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_collections);
        setTitle(R.string.collections);
    }
```

I want to have something like this, Image [One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahI5e.png) Image [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4nvD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setTitle` in your activity.

Comment: I tried that. I was wondering should I disable the manifest label? since all are taking from label manifest.

Comment: You can remove from your manifest. The label is displayed by default on-screen when the activity must be represented to the user.